# 98 suzuki marauder 800. No power at all

Tags: motorcycle, battery, suzuki, fuse

I have put my bike up for the winter and have been starting it periodically. I just went to start and it just lost all power no lights or anything. I have it on a tender and the battery says its at 95 percent. I took off the cover that shows the starter relay and main fuse box.

I moved the main fuse box around it got power back. After it starts and runs for a second it loses all electronic power and shuts off any ideas?

Comment: Have mice been chewing wires? A loose battery cable?

Comment: No i went back out and unplugged the wire running to the main fuse box and bent the propes coming out of it slightly and pluged back in and it seems to be working.